# How to access static fields with reflect in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have this abstract class in java:

```
abstract class AbsApiTestCase<T> {
    T mApi;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mApi = instanceApi((Class<T>) (
                  (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass())
                     .getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
    }

    static <T> T instanceApi(Class<T> clazz) throws Exception {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(clazz.getField("BASE_URL").get(null).toString())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(
                    new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").create()))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .client(getClient())
            .build().create(clazz);

    }
    // some code
}
```

And api looks like this:

```
public interface GithubApi {
    String BASE_URL = "https://api.github.com/";
    // some code
}
```

It can be used like this:

```
public class GithubApiTest extends AbsApiTestCase<GithubApi> {
    // some code
}
```

But when I convert my code to kotlin, the static field `BASE_URL` looks like this:

```
interface GithubApi {
    companion object {
        val BASE_URL = "https://api.github.com/"
    }
    // some code
}
```

And `BASE_URL` cannot be accessed like above. I found there is a `@JvmField` annotation but Android studio says `JvmField cannot be applied to a property defined in companion object of interface`.

Is there a way to access this "static field"?

Comment: how do you plan to use `GithubApi`? Do you need an access from Java?

Comment: @voddan No, I just need a url value to create the instance, and I can't find it in `KClass<T>.members`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about making `BASE_URL` a compile-time constant?

```
interface GithubApi {
    companion object {
        const val BASE_URL = "https://api.github.com/"
    }
}
```

At byte-code level `BASE_URL` is a static field of the `GithubApi` interface.

```
public interface GithubApi {
  public static final GithubApi$Companion Companion;

  public static final java.lang.String BASE_URL;

  static {};
    Code:
       0: new           #26                 // class GithubApi$Companion
       3: dup
       4: aconst_null
       5: invokespecial #30                 // Method GithubApi$Companion."<init>":(Lkotlin/jvm/internal/DefaultConstructorMarker;)V
       8: putstatic     #32                 // Field Companion:LGithubApi$Companion;
      11: return
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `@JvmStatic` annotation will make the property's backing field a static one. That is, if the annotation is applied to a property within a companion object, then a new static field will be created in the enclosing class.

Note that Kotlin really has no notion of static, and that this annotation is merely for accessibility accross JVM languages.

Comment: I also tried `@JvmStatic` too, IDE says `Only functions in named objects and companion objects of classes can be annotated with '@JvmStatic'`.

Answer (score 1):

I see four basic options for that:

1) Extract the property into an object (companion or not):

```
object GithubApiUrls {
    val BASE_URL = "https://api.github.com/"
}
```

2) Make a package-level property:

```
package myProgram

val BASE_URL = "https://api.github.com/"
```

3) Use a class, not an interface, if you need inheritance (no idea what for, TBH):

```
open class GithubApi {
    val BASE_URL = "https://api.github.com/"
}
```

4) Replace the field with a method in the interface (can be overridden):

```
interface GithubApi {
    fun BaseUrl() = "https://api.github.com/"
}
```

Comment: Api interface is used in [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/), it has to be an interface. If I replace it with a function, to access it I need an instance, to create an instance I need the url value, seems like a loop.

Comment: My point is that you don't need to place your static information into the interface. The URL may be stored anywhere (options 1 and 2) near the interface.

Comment: True, I can put it in a map and access it with class name (GithubApi is not the only interface like that, it's not even a real interface in my code, it's just an example), but these code I post is just for test cases, less code and less caring about performance, I do use `Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(GithubApi.BASE_URL)` in real code.

Comment: then maybe a companion object is the way to go

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't suggest putting constants in interfaces at all. It introduces too much complexity without real value gain.

Try decoupling class that holds the constant from the actual class that implements the interface.

```
public class AllUrls {
    public static final String GITHUB_URL = "https://api.github.com/";
}
```

That will become

```
object AllUrls {
    val GITHUB_URL = "https://api.github.com/"
}
```

And to use it

```
 static <T> T instanceApi(Class<T> clazz) throws Exception {
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(AllUrls.INSTANCE.getGITHUB_URL())
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(
                new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").create()))
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
        .client(getClient())
        .build().create(clazz);

}
```

Comment: Using `AllUrls.INSTANCE.getGITHUB_URL()` make this method can be used only for GithubApi now, that case we don't even need a `clazz`. And I don't think putting constants in interface is wrong, there is an integer constant `PARCELABLE_WRITE_RETURN_VALUE` right in `android.os.Parcelable`.