# Kotlin object vs companion-object vs package scoped methods

Tags: static, kotlin, companion-object

I have written this methods in Kotlin and analysed the bytecode:

## Situation 1

```
class A {
    object b {
        fun doSomething() {}
    }
}
```

## Situation 2

```
class A {
    companion object b {
        fun doSomething() {}
    }
}
```

## Situation 3

```
fun doSomething() {}
```

Bytecode Result

- Situation 1: class `Test$asb`, `public final doSomething()I`
- Situation 2: class `Test$Companion`, `public final doSomething()I`
- Situation 3: class `TestKt`, `public final static doSomething()I`

My questions are:

- I have an enum class, and I want to return an enum instace given an enum variable, for instance, findById `(enum(id, color))`. How would I do it? Companion Object? object?
- It seems the only way to have a real static method is in package level, without class declaration. But that becomes a little bit too global. Is there any way to access it via: `ClassName.staticMethod`, staticMethod being really static.
- Provide meaningfull examples of package declaration methods, companion object and object.

Context. I have been coding in Kotlin and I find it amazing. But sometimes I need to make a decision: for example, a heavy immutable property which in java I would declare as static final, but in Kotlin I find it hard to "find an equivalent".

Comment: Maybe this could be of help { http://stackoverflow.com/q/37794850/2804610 }

Comment: In regards to your last paragraph, I think this answer could help you { http://stackoverflow.com/a/37944990/2804610 }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to develop [voddan answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38028276/475857):

```
enum class Color {

    RED,
    BLUE,
    GREEN;


    companion object Utils {
        fun findById(color: Color): Color {
            return color;
        }
    }
}
```

And to test

```
@Test
fun testColor() {
    println(Color.Utils.findById(Color.valueOf("RED")));
}
```

Comment: Why not direct call from `Color` class? `println(Color.findById(Color.valueOf("RED")));`

Answer (score 10):

If you have a function which performs some action closely related to a class but doesn't require a class instance, such as your `findById` example, you should put it in the companion object of the class.

If you want to expose a method as a static method to Java code, you can annotate it with the [`@JvmStatic`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#static-methods) annotation.

Answer (score 7):

If a function does not require an instance of a class, then it is your design decision where to put it. Use package level if it is package-specific, use a class companion if it closely relets to the class (for example other classes in the package have similar functions).

Note that `enum` has several in-build properties and patterns:

```
enum class Colour(val value: Int) {
    black(100), red(200), green(300)
}

fun colourById(id: Int) = Colour.values[id]
fun colourByValue(value: Int) = Colour.values.first {it.value == value}
fun colourByName(name: String) = Colour.valueOf(name)
```